# rosdep and ROS dependencies

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With rosdep2, I'm a bit unclear on one thing. How do you define dependencies on specific ROS stacks? (i.e. so you can have them installed for you with 'rosdep install mystack', and from binary packages if available - for example in Ubuntu)

For example, if I have a stack/package that depends on and uses voxel_grid from the navigation stack, I would put  in my stack.xml/manifest.xml, but if I then run 'rosdep install mystack' or 'rosdep install mypackage' I get an error:
mystack: Missing resource voxel_grid

I can manually remedy this by finding where this package is by using roslocate, and then either install the stack from source or simply install the ros-fuerte-navigation in ubuntu, but is there a way to automatically do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52273/rosdep-and-ros-dependencies/) by [eight](https://answers.ros.org/users/3968/eight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdep is not used for dependencies on other ROS packages.

It is for dependencies on non-ROS packages provided by the underlying operating system.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1